# Java Collections hasnext() and next() method

Tags: java, collections

Iterator is a interface in java and this interface has two main methods
hasNext() and next().

As we know Iterator is a interface and it can't implement these two methods.
so i want to know in which class java implemented these two methods.

We using these method for iterate over list, set and other collection so somehow these methods were implemented.
Please suggest me the class names which implemented above two methods.

Comment: Somewhere in your Java code is the line "Iterator iterator = class.iterator();"  Class is the interface or class that implements the Iterator methods.

Comment: The source code comes with the JDK. Open the ArrayList.java file (for example), and look at the source code of iterator(). Or just browse the code inline: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f#773

Comment: Do you want to discover the implementations programmatically or is a list, tool, or other manual means what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) for `Iterator` provides a list of implementing classes.

Start there and then click your way into those and you can discover a variety of implementations of the `Iterator` interface.

IDEs typically offer a feature that lets you view all interfaces that extend or classes that implement a given interface.

Comment: But the iterators of the collections are not listed there. They're typically private inner classes of their collection, which are not listed in the javadoc.

Comment: Thanks, i got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the `Collection` classes use private inner classes for their `Iterator` implementations that use implementation specific knowledge to iterate more efficiently.

For example here is `java.util.ArrayList` [Iterator implementation from Java 6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr)

Note that it is not a static inner class so it can reference private fields (`modCount`) in the ArrayList to check for ConcurrentModificationExceptions

```
 /**
 * An optimized version of AbstractList.Itr
 */
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
    int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
    int expectedModCount = modCount;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (lastRet < 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        checkForComodification();

        try {
            ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
            cursor = lastRet;
            lastRet = -1;
            expectedModCount = modCount;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }

    final void checkForComodification() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
.... etc


}
```

Comment: Thanks, i got your answer.